# Why can't a Series Converge to 1?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The Divergence Test states:

> If $\sum a_k$ converges, then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = 0$.

Equivalently:

> If $\sum a_k$ diverges, then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k \neq 0$.

---

Why not $1$? If it approaches $1$ it converges to $1$.

Comment: "If it approaches $1$ it converges to $1$". What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: It is not the contapositive

Comment: The contrapositive is that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \neq 0$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. There are divergent series $\sum a_n$ for which $a_n$ converges to zero.

Comment: Maybe I have not understood your question correctly but it seems to me that you are not fully appreciating the difference between the **series** $\sum a_k$ and the **sequence** $\{a_k\}$.

Comment: @Dror Dont go there

Comment: @BDillan Don't go where...? What do you mean?

Comment: @Dror http://imgur.com/LIwsYzx

Comment: @BDillan What you have written is not the same as in the photo you just posted.

Comment: @BDillan That's not what you wrote in the question

Comment: @BDillan, your textbook is correct. You're not appreciating the difference between $A \to B$ and $B \to A$. For example: If I can ride in the tour de france, I have a bicycle. True. If I have a bicycle, I can ride in the tour de france. Much different and not true.

Comment: There I edited it

Comment: @BDillan The contrapositive of "If $A$ then $B$" is "If $\lnot$ $B$ then $\lnot$ $A$". You have assumed the contrapositive of If $A$ then $B$ is If $\lnot A$ then $\lnot$ $B$.

Comment: @BDillan I expanded my answer. Hope this helps now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

$$1+1+1+1+1+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1$$

doesn't converge. This sum is not a finite number. So if there is any hope of an infinite series converging, the terms MUST go to zero. It is not true the other way. Terms going to zero is not enough for convergence with the divergent harmonic series being the classic example.

---

Addendum:

BDillan, you seem confused about two different things.

1.First you seem confused about logic and what the contrapositive statement is for a given statement. If the original statement is $p \Rightarrow q$ then the contrapositive is $\sim q \Rightarrow \sim p$. Your statement 1 is

> If $\sum a_k$ converges, then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = 0$.

You statement 2 is

> If $\sum a_k$ diverges, then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k \neq 0$.

You statement 1 is true. Your statement 2 is not the contrapositive of statement 1 therefore statement 1 and statement 2 are not equivalent. Statement 2 is the inverse of statement 1 ($\sim p \Rightarrow \sim q$). The correct contrapositive is

> If $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k \neq 0$ then $\sum a_k$ diverges.

2.Since the truth of a statement has nothing to do with the truth of its inverse, in this case your statement 2 is false. You seem to confusing the terms of the sequence

$$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...\}$$

and the sequence of partial sums

$$S_1 = a_1$$
$$S_2 = a_1+a_2$$
$$S_3 = a_1+a_2+a_3...$$
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i...$$

An infinite sum converges if an only if the limit of partial sums exists and is finite because

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i = \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n.$$

So once again, if the sum is convergent, then the terms must be going to zero (original statement). If the terms don't go to zero then sum is not convergent (the contrapositive). If the terms do go to zero then we have no idea what happens (the inverse) and we need further investigation.

- The series can converge $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}.$
- It can diverge to positive infinity $\sum \frac{1}{n}.$
- It can diverge to negative infinity $\sum \frac{-1}{n}.$

Comment: So the Value is ∞?

Comment: @BDillan if the **sequence** converges, and not to $0$, the **series** will diverge "to" $\pm \infty$ , with the sign corresponding to the sign of the limit of the sequence. But, the sequence might not have an extended limit at all.. Take $-1^n$ for example. $\sum -1^n$ diverges, but not to any infinity

Comment: I meant $(-1)^n$. Teehee.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of "If $A$ then $B$" is "If $\lnot$ $B$ then $\lnot$ $A$".

You have assumed that "If $A$ then $B$" is equivalent to "If $\lnot A$ then $\lnot$ $B$". However, **this is not the case**.

The *contrapositive* of "If $\sum a_k$ converges then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = 0$" is: 
"If $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k \ne 0$ then $\sum a_k$ diverges. "

The *inverse* of "If $\sum a_k$ converges then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k = 0$" is: 
 If "$\sum a_k$ diverges then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k \ne 0$". 
 These two statements are **$\large \textbf{not equivalent}$**.

One is true, while the other is blatantly false. 
For example:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} = +\infty \text{ but } \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0
$$
which directly contradicts 
 
If "$\sum a_k$ diverges then $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k \ne 0$"

Comment: let it go.. :-). The more important thing is your health!

Comment: @Dror deal. i'll rest my case.

Comment: @Dror You are funny, ha ha

Comment: What's the problem man?

Comment: @Dror No, i genuinely thought your comment about health was true and it was witty-- it made me laugh

Comment: Oh, I see.. "Sounded" like the direct opposite to my negation-savvy ears

Comment: So did the -6 downvotes come from the contrapositive? Or was it because I edited it.

Comment: Honestly you cant be downvoted for being dumb. Questions are asked and questions need answers

Comment: @bdillan I didn't down vote you nor do I think u are dumb. Cheers